# Phpstorm creating random diffs that I did not make

Tags: git, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm as my IDE. I'm also using Git as my VCS.

I go to certain files and make some changes; however, for some reason, PHPStorm would also automatically create other diffs that I did not make, and those diffs are simply removing and re-adding the same lines without changing them.

For instance, suppose I have xyz.php:

```
$j = 1;
$f = 2;
```

...then I make some little change

```
$j = 1;
$f = 2;
$x = 3; //added this change - that's it
```

and then save.

Running a `git diff` would reveal:

```
-$j = 1;
+$j = 1;
-$f = 2;
+$f = 2;
+$x = 3; //added this change - that's it
```

This happens consistently within a select few files.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this and how to make it stop happening?

Also, if it helps, if I edit the file in Eclipse or any other editor, this doesn't happen.

Comment: [CRLF difference](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I tried git config --global core.autocrlf true but it didnt work...